# max voltage level for Rx and Tx:mbed lpc1768

Tags: uart, mbed, tx

I have an mbed board with LPC 1768. I want to receive serial data from a zigbee adapter which works on 5V. The voltage beween the Rx Tx pin and ground of the adapter is around 4.99 V. Is it safe to connect it directly to the mbed board Rx, Tx.

Comment: I don't think `system.reactive` is the tag you were looking for.  That tag is for the Reactive Extensions framework for .NET (which is often referred to as Rx).

Comment: Yes..my mistake. ..I will correct it. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. You may be able to get help at a different [se] site such as [electronics.se] instead. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the LPC1768 pins are 5V tolerant, so you can connect them to a 5V system without damaging the CPU.

To make sure that the pins in question are indeed 5V tolerant check the data-sheet: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf

All pins are listed in section 7.2. You may have to take a look at the mbed schematic to find out which CPU pins are used for your UART.

You also have to make sure that the 5V system will interpret the 3.3V output level of the LPC1768 as logic high levels. Most chips will work fine and interpret anything higher than 2.5V as logic high but there are some exceptions out there that need a higher level. Those won't be damaged but you won't be able to communicate with them without the help of a level-shifter.